# How do I store values of arbitrary type in a single Django model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Say I have the unknown number of questions.  For example:

- Is the sky blue [y/n]
- What date were your born on [date]
- What is pi [3.14]
- What is a large integ [100]

Now each of these questions poses a different but very type specific answer (boolean, date, float, int).  Natively django can happily deal with these in a model.

```
class SkyModel(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField("Is the sky blue")
    answer = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class BirthModel(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField("What date were your born on")
    answer = models.DateTimeField(default=today)

class PiModel(models.Model)
    question = models.CharField("What is pi")
    answer = models.FloatField()
```

But this has the obvious problem in that each question has a specific model - so if we need to add a question later I have to change the database. Yuck.  So now I want to get fancy - How do a set up a model where by the answer type conversion happens automagically?

```
ANSWER_TYPES = (
    ('boolean', 'boolean'),
    ('date', 'date'),
    ('float', 'float'),
    ('int', 'int'),
    ('char', 'char'),
)

class Questions(models.model):
    question = models.CharField(()
    answer = models.CharField()
    answer_type = models.CharField(choices = ANSWER_TYPES)
    default = models.CharField()
```

So in theory this would do the following:

- When I build up my views I look at the type of answer and ensure that I
  only put in that value.
- But when I want to pull that answer back out it will return the data in the format specified by the answer_type.  Example 3.14 comes back out as a float not as a str.

How can I perform this sort of automagic transformation?  Or can someone suggest a better way to do this?

Thanks much!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I actually just faced this type of problem regarding extensible user settings. My solution was to store the type on the model in a `CharField` and use a getter to do the type conversion with a smart use of `__builtin__` and `getattr`. This is my code (adapt for your needs):

```
VALUE_TYPE_CHOICES = (
    ("unicode", "Unicode String"),
    ("int", "Integer"),
    ("bool", "Boolean"),
)

class Setting(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=VALUE_TYPE_CHOICES)
    default_value = models.CharField(max_length=127)

def get_setting(user, setting_id):
    profile_setting = #get the user's specific setting value here, not relevant
    type = getattr(__builtin__, profile_setting.setting.type)
    if type is bool:
        return type(int(profile_setting.value))
    else:
        return type(profile_setting.value)
```

There's one gotcha in there: `bool('0')` actually returns `True`, so I chose to typecast to `int` before typecasting to `bool`. There are other ways you can accomplish this, like using the `ast` module's `literal_eval` method instead. Overall the pattern works, though.

Answer (score 2):

You should be fine just storing the answers as strings. If we're talking about accepting data over the web, you're going to receive your input as a string anyway, so you're not losing precision by storing it in the database as a string.

One possible alternative would be to include one column for each possible data type, allowing them to be null.

```
class Questions(models.model):
    question = models.CharField(()
    answer = models.CharField()
    answer_type = models.CharField(choices = ANSWER_TYPES)
    int_answer = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    bool_answer = models.NullBooleanField(null=True)
    ... etc.
```

If it were me, I'd stick with a single `CharField` though.

Comment: Storing it as a string is the way to go, IMHO, but having a good strategy for typecasting back to the original value is important. Having different fields for each type of answer just sounds extra-messy.

Answer (score 2):

I would add a custom method to your Questions class:

```
def get_converted_answer(self):
  if self.answer_type == 'int':
    return int(self.answer)
  if self.answer_type == 'bool':
    # ...
```

Comment: I considered doing it this way, and realized I could get tricky and avoid writing all the extra ifs using the logic in my post above. Definitely the right idea, though.